# Subscription is not assigneable to type route

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-routing

I am trying to set canActivate route but I am getting syntax error(Subscription is not assigneable to type route):

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
const pin = route.paramMap.get('pin');
let canActivate;
if (pin) {
  return this.partService.getCached(pin).pipe(
     take(1),
     concatMap(p => { 
       if(this.appService.isUserAuthorized(Authorization.canAccessAll_View, p))
       { 
         return of(true);
       }
       return this.partService.getEnrolled(pin,'WW')
  })).subscribe(parts => {
        if(parts)
        {
          parts.forEach(part => {
            if (part.agencyCode == this.appService.user.agencyCode) {
              if (this.appService.isUserAuthorizedToView(part)) {
                canActivate = true;
              } else {
                this.routeToUnauthorized(state.url);
                canActivate = false;
              }

            }
          });
        } 
        return canActivate;       
  });      

}
```

}

What is wrong in the syntax here?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: why do you subscribe? You have to return a boolean, a Promise<boolean>, or an Observable<boolean>. Please review the CanActivate interface documentation as well as rxjs basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subscribing, try mapping. Like cghislai mentioned, you have to either return a boolean, Promise, or Observable;

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
const pin = route.paramMap.get('pin');
let canActivate = false; // initialize with a false value
if (pin) {
  return this.partService.getCached(pin).pipe(
     take(1),
     concatMap(p => { 
       if(this.appService.isUserAuthorized(Authorization.canAccessAll_View, p))
       { 
         return of(true);
       }
       return this.partService.getEnrolled(pin,'WW');
  }),
  map(parts => {
    if(parts)
        {
          parts.forEach(part => {
            if (part.agencyCode == this.appService.user.agencyCode) {
              if (this.appService.isUserAuthorizedToView(part)) {
                canActivate = true;
              } else {
                this.routeToUnauthorized(state.url);
                canActivate = false;
              }
            }
          });
        } 
        return canActivate;
  }));
}
```